# modification in huffman coding

Tags: c++, priority-queue, huffman-code

When I was studying huffman coding, I faced a problem while dealing with priority queue. Since I am not So good at cpp Please help.

[Here is the code](https://www.techiedelight.com/huffman-coding/)

I tried to make some changes that I have learned so far in cpp.
In above cpp program I changed below part of code

```
struct Node
{
    char ch;
    int freq;
    Node *left, *right;
};


struct comp
{
    bool operator()(Node* l, Node* r)
    {
        // highest priority item has lowest frequency
        return l->freq > r->freq;
    }
```

};

and using it as `priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, comp> pq` in `buidingHuffmanTree()` function.

I changed it to

```
struct Node
{
    char ch; 
    int freq;
    Node *left, *right;
    bool operator<(Node const& other) {
    return freq < other.freq;
}
};
```

Now I tried to use it like 
`priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>> pq`

But I am getting wrong answers. In above program input is static you can see that 
answers is exactly (input output is large i can't write here )

Also tried to change the signs  as `freq > other.freq` instead of `<` getting wrong answers

As both pieces of code are working differently, I thought they will work in the same way.

Comment: Oh, and this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521936/comparator-for-stl-containers-cpp (but marginally better formulated).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your queue stores *pointers* to `Node` objects, not actual `Node` object instances themselves.

The `comp` structure handles that with its function-call operator, but your member `operator<` overload doesn't handle pointers.

More specifically, for member operator overloading, the left-hand side *must* be an object instance (which the function is called on), and not a pointer.

---

If you don't want to use functor objects but instead want to use operator overloading, you can make a non-member function that takes two pointers as arguments:

```
struct Node
{
    char ch; 
    int freq;
    Node *left, *right;

    // By using `friend` we declare this as a non-member function
    friend bool operator<(Node const* left, Node const* right)
        return left->freq < right->freq;
    }
};
```

Comment: `bool operator<(Node* other) {
    return freq < other->freq;` i changed to this but still getting wrong

Comment: so you want to say that i cant use operator overloading here

Comment: Mean i have only first option to use,I just want to use the second one

Comment: @user451 You can, but not as a member function. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Any changes here `priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>> pq` or will it work fine